# Getting images from an endpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using ajax to get an array of image names from a service.
When I inspect data.d the array is there. However, I can't seem to assign it to my variable because when I alert it it says undefined.

And what is `data.d` all about as far as accessing the return array? Why `.d`?

Is there a better way to do this? I'm going to take array of image names and cycle through them later in the program.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>

        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var aryImageNames;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetImages",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{}",
                success: function (data) {
                    aryImageNames = data.d;
                }
            });

            alert(aryImageNames);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `.d` is just a result of how your endpoint was constructed. It's not a jQuery/JavaScript standard.

As for why you might be seeing `undefined` when alerting `aryImageNames`, I suspect it may be due to the async nature of JavaScript. In other words, your AJAX call may not completed before `alert(aryImageNames)` is called.

You'll have to make sure that any code processing the images be called after it is done. For example, if you want to alert the image names, you'll need to put it in the success callback like so:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetImages",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{}",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        });
```

This ensures that the alert will only occur once the result has been retrieved from your endpoint.

Comment: But I need to use the array later on outside the success or ajax scope. How would I do that?

Comment: You can still set the array as a global variable. You can then maybe prevent the usage of the areas that depend on the array until it is loaded (use the success callback to "activate"/reveal the area once the data has loaded). Imagine something like a loading screen?